# Screencasts on writing testable JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, testing, tdd, automated-tests

Are there any screencasts that would dive deeply in writing testable JavaScript code?
Also explaining practices, tools, etc.

Preferably something well polished and presented as PeepCode's ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that [PeopCode's Backbone screencast](http://peepcode.com/products/backbone-ii) series to be a good one.

It does indeed show how you can do unit-testing apart from other stuff.

Comment: Any update on the link?

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at [this video from NDC 2010](http://tekpub.com/conferences/ndc2010/test-driven-javascript). It might not cover all your requirements but it was a good starting point for me.

Comment: Good one indeed. But I would really like to find some quality screencasts (like PeepCode's) with the details and stuff. Talks are really good and inspiring, but the evil is in the details.

Comment: The Semicolon&Sons YouTube channel has a focus on testing from the indie-hacker perspective where programming time must compete with time spent marketing. Therefore smoke-screen techniques like automatically causing Selenium integration tests to fail upon any JS exception on any page are explored: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC17mJJnvzAa_e9qQqLIfIeQ

Answer (score 0):

After this question was posted, there was a talk about [writing testable JavaScript](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OzjogCFO4Zo) at Full Frontal 2012.

The author also wrote the [#1 google hit](https://www.google.de/search?q=testable%20javascript): [Writing Testable JavaScript · An A List Apart Article](http://alistapart.com/article/writing-testable-javascript).